# How to get and set XORWOWRandomNumberGenerator state for persistence?

Tags: python, pycuda

My goal is to persist the full state of each iteration of a complex algorithm which also involves pseudo-random numbers generated via `pycuda`. In order to resume the algorithm at an arbitraty iteration and deterministically reproduce the same results, I need something similar to [get_state() and set_state() from numpy.random.RandomState](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.get_state.html#numpy.random.RandomState.get_state)

Considering this:

```
from pycuda.curandom import XORWOWRandomNumberGenerator
gen = XORWOWRandomNumberGenerator()
```

How can I obtain the full state of `gen` in order to load it into `numpy` arrays?

How to reproduce the exact same state of `gen` based on these previously obtained `numpy` arrays?

Answer (score 1):

I did not find an out-of-the-box solution. Thus, I derived the following class from `XORWOWRandomNumberGenerator`:

```
from pycuda.curandom import XORWOWRandomNumberGenerator
import pycuda.driver as drv
import numpy


class PersistableXORWOWRandomNumberGenerator(XORWOWRandomNumberGenerator):
    def get_state_size(self):
        from pycuda.characterize import sizeof
        data_type_size = sizeof(self.state_type, "#include <curand_kernel.h>")
        return self.block_count * self.generators_per_block * data_type_size

    def get_state(self, ary=None):
        if ary is None:
            ary = drv.from_device(self.state, (self.get_state_size(),), numpy.uint8)
        else:
            drv.memcpy_dtoh(ary, self.state)
        return ary

    def set_state(self, state):
        drv.memcpy_htod(self.state, state)
```

It can be used like this:

```
gen = PersistableXORWOWRandomNumberGenerator()

# obtain the random state as a uint8 numpy array
state_as_numpy = gen.get_state()

# set the state from a uint8 numpy array
gen.set_state(state_as_numpy)
```